# Using class or id in HTML to identify similar objects

Tags: html, class

I made an HTML+CSS+JS project which simulates the Djikstra algoritm. The code let's you to draw nodes on the page. A node is made by an image and a text.

The image is the same for every node, but the text is different for each node.
Should i identify each node with an id or with class?
Right now i identify each node like this ( using id ):

```
<div id="node01">
<img src="back.png"></img>
<div>node text</div>
</div>

<div id="node02">
<img src="back.png"></img>
<div>another node text</div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: The class selector is used to specify a style for a group of elements. Unlike the id selector, the class selector is most often used on several elements.So class is definitely ideal in this situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to identify each node as an individual (for example to read it's contents) then you should continue to use IDs, but also use a class so that you can style each of your nodes the same way. If you don't need to select them as individuals then remove the ID and just keep the classes.

Comment: Yes, the style is done by using a class, and yes i need to read the content of the node.